# Fatal error: in ftp_login

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to upload image file to remote server using php, i am able to make ftp connection successfully, but cannot login using `ftp_login`, it gives me error as `Fatal error:`

**php**

```
require_once('../rmconn.php');

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($rmhost, 21) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$ftp_login = @ftp_login($ftp_conn, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($rmconn), E_USER_ERROR);

ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

if ($ftp_login) {
    echo "Connected as $user@$rmhost\n";
} else {
    echo "Couldn't connect as $user";
}

ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Please see and suggest any possible way do this.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because of `mysqli_connect_error()`

Comment: What is the fatal error you are getting?

Comment: it just says `Fatal error: in...at line 4`, and Couldn't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem lies here:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($rmhost, 21) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$ftp_login = @ftp_login($ftp_conn, $user, $pass) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($rmconn), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Specifically in the `mysqli_error` part. Replace like this:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($rmhost, 21) or die("could not connect");
$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $user, $pass) or die("could not login");
```

I also removed the `@` before `ftp_login`. While debugging, you should suppress warnings and errors.

Comment: now it gives me error as `could not login` and removing @ gives error `ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in`

Comment: A well. There you have it. `$ftp_conn` is `null` instead of a resource. The problem thus lies in `ftp_connect`. What is `$rmhost` set to?

Comment: @TallboY `ftp_connect` does not return `null`. Make sure, you've spelled correctly `$ftp_conn` in `ftp_login` function..

Comment: @Bart Friederichs `$rmhost` is set to my remote host ip `184.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: @PLB i checked it, there is no misspelling.

Comment: Try to remove the port number, it 21 by default anyway.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs i am getting this error now using your way,`ftp_login(): Login authentication failed in`, previous error is because i used escape in login part.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs username/password are correct, i can connect like, `$rmconn = mysqli_connect($rmhost, $user, $pass, $db) or trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
`

Comment: @Bart Friederichs if i use `@ftp_login` insted of `ftp_login` it does not show `ftp_login(): Login authentication failed in`, but shows `could not login`

Comment: No. `mysqli_connect` connects to a **database server**, `ftp_connect` connects to an **FTP server**, two completely different things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23618/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-tall-boy)